# What to do with non-tradeable recipes

Tags: spiral-knights

I have bought jelly recipes in Hall of Heroes to sell it later, but after I got back to baazar I saw that it is not tradeable. Should I leave this mess in my pack?

Comment: I made the same mistake. I bought recipes from the HoH without realizing I was given them as mission rewards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sell them in the Bazaar to [Quillian](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Quillion), the Blade Merchant.

Comment: For about how much?  You can sell them in the HoH too, but they only give you 25cr for a 25k cr recipe...